# How to generate a new request with some delay after get the response in Jmeter performance test?

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario like this:

1. The client send a HTTP request A,
2. The client then receives a response with the `<requestId>` generated by server.
3. Then after a while (say always 1 seconds),
4. The client generate another reqeust B to query the result via this `<requestId>`.

How would I use Jmeter to simulate such clients in an efficient way?

I can get the `<requestId>` by the regular expression extractor but how would I then control Jmeter in order to send another request with some delay?

Answer (score 1):

`Constant Timer` : If you want to have each thread pause for the same amount of time between requests, use this timer. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer

You can use `Constant Timer` element as `post processor` or `pre processor` for the request based on either you want to wait before or after the request.